# Добавление записи через функцию класса первой таблицы в другую таблицу

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

При использовании SQLAlchemy имеется к примеру два класса описывающих таблицы User и Contact. При этом Contact имеет связь многие к одному к каждой строке на User.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contact"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    contact = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

Можно ли, и если да, то как, описать функцию в классе User типа add_contact, которая добавит запись в таблицу Contact?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ясна задача, но если очень хочется, то можно конечно:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

    def add_contact(self, contact):
        contact.user_id = self.id
        db_session.add(contact)
        db_session.commit()

    # ИЛИ
    def add_contact(self, contact_name):
        contact = Contact(user_id = self.id, contact = contact_name)
        db_session.add(contact)
        db_session.commit()

class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contact"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    contact = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)

    user = relationship(User, backref=backref("contacts"))

    def __init__(self, user_id, contact_name):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.contact = contact_name
```